# WordPress thumbnail adds height and weight to my src image

Tags: wordpress, height, width

Well, that's pretty much it. Imagine that I upload an image named: https://hellothere.png. WordPress Blog Section will change my thumbnail image with something like this: "https://hellothere-250x150.png". This is bummer, actually, because it messes up the quality of the image.

How can I avoid this behavior? Been looking throughout the code for a while now, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't embed the thumbnail, embed the full image: https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages unless you mean the thumbnail on the blog archive, in which case it ma be to do with your theme and require a code change to the theme

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail default size is set in settings. You can also get the full size by function:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
```